# Symmetric groups of the circle and the order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Let $C$ be the symmetric group for the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a $c \in C$ for which $|c|= n$.

The symmetric group of the circle is $\{e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}\}$ where $i^2=-1,k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq0},n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$? Also the symmetric group is infinite so there should be such $c$. I would need some hints on how to approach the proof?

Comment: How are you interpreting $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ as an element of the symmetry group of the circle? (Also, the symmetry of the circle is uncountably infinite, so this will not describe the entire group in any case).

Comment: Couldn't I rotate the circle by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ for $n \to \infty$?

Comment: You can do that for every $n$, but you could also rotate the circle by, for example, $\frac{2\pi}{e}$ radians or $2\pi/\sqrt{5}$ radians. If what you mean is a **rotation** by $2\pi/n$, I would call this something like $R_{2\pi/n}$ or $\theta_{2\pi/n}$ or something rather than just writing the number by itself.